# C# Exception: RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to restore a database backup file (`.bak`) to a newly created database using C#. I get the following inner exception:

> Cannot open backup device '\GC.bak'. Operating system error 5 (Access is denied.).
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

My server is a localDB.

```
void RestoreDB(string name)
{
    var connection = new ServerConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Well);

    var sqlServer = new Server(connection);

    var rstDatabase = new Restore();
    rstDatabase.Database = name;
    rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    rstDatabase.Devices.AddDevice(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "GC.bak", DeviceType.File);
    rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
}
```

Comment: Are you running this with Administrator rights? Just a thought.

Comment: @PiyushParashar I am the only user. And my account is admin

Comment: Consider using System.Environment.CurrentDirectory instead of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.

Comment: @enkryptor Thank you for that. I will consider that

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server only has access to a few specific places on the server drive (i.e. the default database and backup folder locations). It looks like you are probably trying to restore the file from a non-standard location, so you either need to grant permissions to the service account that SQL server is running under to that directory, or even easier, copy the backup file into the regular backup file location and try again.

Comment: I have put the mdf to the default location. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA. Or is it the location of my .bak file you are talking about?

Comment: The bak file is the one causing you the problem.

Comment: How do I give MSSQLSERVER permission to a specific folder (my bak folder)? I mean, what name do I put in the security?